# cannot handle net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in pure js

Tags: javascript, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I use pure js(without JQuery) to send an `XMLHttpRequest` request to server.

```
        var _xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        _xhr.open(type, url);
        _xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        _xhr.responseType = 'json';
        _xhr.onload = function () {
            if (_xhr.status === 200) {
                var _json = _xhr.response;
                if (typeof _json == 'string')
                    _json = JSON.parse(_json);
                success(_json);
            } else {
                error(_xhr);
            }
        };
        _xhr.onerror = function(){
            console.log('fail');
        };
        try {
            _xhr.send(_to_send);
        } catch (e){
            options.error(_xhr);
        }
```

when i send a request it's fails(this is ok) and i get an error but I CANNON HANDLE IT. `xhr.onerror` prints message to console but i get `OPTIONS url net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` too. How can I avoid this message in console?

Also i use `window.onerror` to handle all error but i can not handle this `OPTIONS url net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
// Watch for net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and other oddities.
_xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (_xhr.readyState == 4 && _xhr.status == 0) {
    console.log('OH NO!');
  }
};
```

This is not limited to just **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** because other network errors (e.g. *net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED*, *net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE*, *net::ERR_TIMED_OUT*) may be "caught" this way. I am unable to locate these error messages within the _xhr object anywhere, so making a programmatic decision about which network error has specifically occurred won't be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around that error showing in console. Just as if you request a file that does't exist you get a `404` in console, regardless of if you handle the error or not.